# Displaying a tooltip on mouse hover of an HTML submit button

Tags: css

I have a simple link on my JSP page as shown below.

```
<a href="" title="Press the button to delete the row." class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>
```

It displays an icon and when mouse hovers over it, it displays a tooltip with another icon as shown in the following snap shot.

[image]

The tooltip is displayed at the last row of the last column of the above HTML table.

The css class to display a default icon is as follows.

```
a.icon-2    
{
    background: url(../images/table/table_icon_2.gif) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
    width: 24px;   /*Displays a default icon*/
}
```

When mouse hovers over the link, the default icon is replaced by the following css class.

```
a:hover.icon-2  
{
   background: url(../images/table/table_icon_2.gif) 0 -24px; 
   /*Displays icon on mouse hover.*/
}
```

and the css class which actually displays the tooltip is as follows.

```
#tooltip    
{
    background-color: #8c8c8c;
    border: 1px solid #767676;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    opacity: 0.85;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

Now, I need to display the same tooltip with the same icon on HTML submit buttons on mouse hover `<input type="submit">`. How can it be displayed?

Comment: The same way, but using CSS selectors for your `submit` button instead of `a` links...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `a:hover.icon-2`, try `.icon-2:hover`.